# Design table that it's <th> have long name with sorting sign and textbox for search

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, templates, responsive-design

[image]

```js
< script >
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $("#table_filter_simab_btn").click(function() {
      $("#table_filter_simab_btn").fadeOut(1);
      $(".searching_input_simab").fadeIn(3000);
      $("#table_filter_simab_btn_cancel").fadeIn(3000);
      $("#table_filter_simab_btn_check").fadeIn(3000);
    })
    $("#table_filter_simab_btn_cancel").click(function() {
      $(".searching_input_simab").fadeOut(1);
      $("#table_filter_simab_btn_cancel").fadeOut(1);
      $("#table_filter_simab_btn_check").fadeOut(1);
      $("#table_filter_simab_btn").fadeIn(2000);
    })
  });

<
/script>
```

```css
<style>#searching_div_simab #searching_table_simab #searching_thead_simab #searching_tr_simab .searching_input_simab {
  display: none;
}

#searching_div_simab #searching_table_simab #searching_thead_simab #searching_tr_simab #table_filter_simab_btn_cancel {
  display: none;
}

#searching_div_simab #searching_table_simab #searching_thead_simab #searching_tr_simab #table_filter_simab_btn_check {
  display: none;
}

#searching_div_simab #searching_table_simab #searching_thead_simab #searching_tr_simab .fit {
  white-space: pre;
  width: 1%;
}

#searching_div_simab #searching_table_simab #records_table tr td {
  white-space: pre;
  width: 1%;
}

</style>
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel-content" id="searching_div_simab">
  <table class="table table-hover dataTable table-bordered" id="searching_table_simab">
    <thead id="searching_thead_simab">
      <tr id="searching_tr_simab" role="row">
        <th class="fit" rowspan="1" colspan="1">
          action <br />
          <button id="table_filter_simab_btn" class="btn btn-sm btn-blue" style="width:40px;"><i class="fa fa-filter"></i>  filter  </button>
          <button id="table_filter_simab_btn_check" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" style="width:40px;"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> submit  </button>
          <button id="table_filter_simab_btn_cancel" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" style="width:40px;"><i class="fa fa-close"></i>  cancel  </button>
        </th>
        <th class="sorting fit" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Title of the column<input class="form-control searching_input_simab" placeholder="Search..." type="text"></th>
        <th class="sorting fit" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Title of the column<input class="form-control searching_input_simab" placeholder="Search..." type="text"></th>
        <th class="sorting fit" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Title of the column<input class="form-control searching_input_simab" placeholder="Search..." type="text"></th>
        <th class="sorting fit" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Title of the column<input class="form-control searching_input_simab" placeholder="Search..." type="text"></th>
        <th class="sorting fit" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Title of the column<input class="form-control searching_input_simab" placeholder="Search..." type="text"></th>
        <th class="sorting fit" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Title of the column<input class="form-control searching_input_simab" placeholder="Search..." type="text"></th>
        <th class="sorting fit" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Title of the column<input class="form-control searching_input_simab" placeholder="Search..." type="text"></th>
        <th class="sorting fit" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Title of the column<input class="form-control searching_input_simab" placeholder="Search..." type="text"></th>
        <th class="sorting fit" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Title of the column<input class="form-control searching_input_simab" placeholder="Search..." type="text"></th>
        <th class="sorting fit" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Title of the column<input class="form-control searching_input_simab" placeholder="Search..." type="text"></th>
        <th class="sorting fit" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Title of the column<input class="form-control searching_input_simab" placeholder="Search..." type="text"></th>
        <th class="sorting fit" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Title of the column <input class="form-control searching_input_simab" placeholder="Search..." type="text"></th>
        <th class="sorting fit" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Title of the column <input class="form-control searching_input_simab" placeholder="Search..." type="text"></th>
        <th class="sorting fit" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Title of the column <input class="form-control searching_input_simab" placeholder="Search..." type="text"></th>
        <th class="sorting fit" rowspan="1" colspan="1"> Title of the column <input class="form-control searching_input_simab" placeholder="Search..." type="text"></th>
        <th class="sorting fit" rowspan="1" colspan="1"> Title of the column<input class="form-control searching_input_simab" placeholder="Search..." type="text"></th>
        <th class="sorting fit" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Title of the column <input class="form-control searching_input_simab" placeholder="Search..." type="text"></th>
        <th class="sorting fit" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Title of the column <input class="form-control searching_input_simab" placeholder="Search..." type="text"></th>
        <th class="sorting fit" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Title of the column <input class="form-control searching_input_simab" placeholder="Search..." type="text"></th>
        <th class="sorting fit" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Title of the column <input class="form-control searching_input_simab" placeholder="Search..." type="text"></th>
        <th class="sorting fit" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Title of the column <input class="form-control searching_input_simab" placeholder="Search..." type="text"></th>
        <th class="sorting fit" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Title of the column<input class="form-control searching_input_simab" placeholder="Search..." type="text"></th>
        <th class="sorting fit" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Title of the column <input class="form-control searching_input_simab" placeholder="Search..." type="text"></th>
        <th class="sorting fit" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Title of the column<input class="form-control searching_input_simab" placeholder="Search..." type="text"></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="records_table">
      <tr>
        <td class="text-right">
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td><button type="button" title="delete" style="width:32px;" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".modal" data-paragraphs="10"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></button></td>
              <td><button type="button" title="edit" style="width:32px;" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".modal" data-paragraphs="10"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></button></td>
              <td><button type="button" title="info" style="width:32px;" class="btn btn-sm btn-dark" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".modal" data-paragraphs="10"><i class="fa fa-info"></i></button></td>
              <td><button type="button" title="price" style="width:32px;" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".modal" data-paragraphs="10"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i></button></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
        <td>super Admin</td>
        <td>super Admin</td>
        <td>super Admin</td>
        <td>super Admin</td>
        <td>super Admin</td>
        <td>super Admin</td>
        <td>super Admin</td>
        <td>super Admin</td>
        <td>super Admin</td>
        <td>super Admin</td>
        <td>super Admin</td>
        <td>super Admin</td>
        <td>super Admin</td>
        <td>super Admin</td>
        <td>super Admin</td>
        <td>super Admin</td>
        <td>super Admin</td>
        <td>super Admin</td>
        <td>super Admin</td>
        <td>super Admin</td>
        <td>super Admin</td>
        <td>super Admin</td>
        <td>super Admin</td>
        <td>super Admin</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

I want to design table that it's `<th>` have long name with a sorting sign and textbox for search. This table has a lot of columns.

How should I style the table that long content along with a sorting sign put in one row and textbox below them regularly and uniformly? Due to the larg number of columns this table has horizontal scroll.

Example:

```
 <th class="sorting" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Title of the program<input class="form-control searching_input_asd" placeholder="Search" type="text"></th>
```

Comment: Please read the [help] before posting.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. Anyway, if you want the input below the text, just insert a <br>. Or do you mean you want the text and the input on the same line if the screen is wide enough, and only wrap on narrower screens? Maybe screenshots of what you want would be helpful.

Comment: i add source code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have looked up and down, tried all the different and various ways of being able to solve this problem,Then I find the Solution.
You can use the `text-overflow` Property in CSS to not write long titles in multiple lines.

Use this Style :

```
th.fit {
    white-space: nowrap; 
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Check out this [Link](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-overflow.asp) for more details.